# blenderplayer.app won't open

Tags: game-engine, osx

I just downloaded Blender, and when I try to open blenderplayer.app it bounces in the dock (I'm on a MacBook Pro using Yosemite) and doesn't open. Can anyone advise me as to what to do? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You don't run `blenderplayer.app` by itself like that by default, you would launch this from the command line if you wanted to tweak how the game is run (see the arguments it takes [here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/blenderplayer.1.html)). It is used to [execute games](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Game_Engine/Blender_Player) that you exported. To launch the actual application use `blender.app`.